# Bootstrap datetimepicker appears at the top-left corner of the window

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the date time picker from God knows where but it just happens to be there in a set of files with the naming convention `bootstrap-datetimepicker-min.js` and `.css`. I assume this is one of the bootstrap widgets, then, which I should think is based on jQuery UI's date time picker. Anyway, the API is pretty similar to the jQuery UI date time picker.

So, I have this code but the date time picker shows up on the top-left corner of the window once I click on the date input field, and then it does not go away either.

**ThePage.cshtml**

```
...

<!-- stuff -->

<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FromDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2"})
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="text"class="form-control" id="dtFromDate" name="FromDate" />
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FromDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

@section scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(Initialize);

        function Initialize()
        {
            $('#dtFromDate').datetimepicker();
            $('#dtToDate').datetimepicker();
        }
    </script>
}
```

And the layout page has the include statements to include the right JavaScript and CSS files:

**Layout.cshtml**

```
<!-- on the top of the page somewhere -->
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")

...
<!-- stuff -->

<!-- at the bottom of the layout page -->
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/components")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

**BundleConfig.cs**

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/site.css",
                      "~/Content/Calendar/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css",
                      "~/Content/select2/css/select2.min.css"
                      ));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                      "~/Scripts/respond.js"
                      ));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/components").Include(
                "~/Content/Calendar/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js",
                      "~/Content/select2/js/select2.full.min.js",
                      "~/Content/select2/js/i18n/en.js"
                ));
```

Comment: this might help http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&maxViewMode=2&todayBtn=false&clearBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox

Comment: You need to use orientation parameter for `datetimepicker` function

Comment: http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/

Comment: third one is for `datetimepicker` specially and first one is its ancestor. ;)

Comment: @GHOST93 Thank you. You seem to know stuff. I am so confused. I opened the first link you sent. I have seen it in Google searches but have no idea what it is. What have I just opened? Who made it?

Comment: And also, how many of these are there?

Comment: I changed it to use a jQuery UI datepicker and it works fine now. Thank goodness for jQuery UI.

Answer (score 0):

Well it's obviously not ideal but this is a quick fix that will work in CSS

```
span.select2-container[style='position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;'] {
    display: none;
}
```